# Custom Permalinks for Custom Post Types and Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting

I've been struggling with this for hours.

I'm trying to get this URL structure:
`example.com/business/%custom-tax-name%/%custom-post-name%/`
By custom tax name I don't mean the name of the taxonomy ("Location"), I mean the value that is chosen for that particular post, which will be a city name. So,
`example.com/business/long-island-city/business-name`
or
`example.com/business/phoenix/business-name/`

So far I've made a custom taxonomy:

```
$singular = 'Merchant Location';
$plural = 'Merchant Locations';
$taxonomy_args = array(
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'business-location',
        'with_front' => FALSE,
        'hierarchical' => FALSE
    )
);  
// Register taxonomy ...
```

and have changed the links in the `post_type_link` filter

```
function filter_business_permalinks($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {

if ($post->post_type == 'my_custom_post_type') {
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'my_custom_taxonomy');
     foreach ($terms as $term) {
         $post_link = str_replace('business/', 'business/'. $term->slug .'/', $post_link);
         break;
     }

return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_business_permalinks', 10, 4);
```

And the resulting URL is fine after that, just what I wanted, so the filter function is working perfectly. However when I click the URL, it goes to this:
`example.com/business/long-island-city/long-island-city/business-name`
which yields a 404.

What could be causing this and how could I fix it?

All help is greatly appreciated.

**Note:**
What I don't want is a URL structure like this:
`example.com/business/location/long-island-city/business-name/`
having the taxonomy *name* in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the method I use to get what you're trying to achieve.

First, register your location taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'location',
    array( 'business' ),
    array(
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'business-location' )
    )
);
```

Next, register the business post type. The important bit to note here is the inclusion of the `%location%` rewrite tag in the slug. We'll use that to replace with the location term in the `post_type_link` function:

```
register_post_type(
    'business',
    array(
        'label' => 'Business',
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'business/%location%' ),
        'hierarchical' => false
    )
);
```

Now the function to swap in the location term:

```
function wpa_business_permalinks( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'business' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'location' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%location%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_business_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've flushed the permalinks and now this works: `example.com/business`  but this doesn't:  `example.com/business/long-island-city/business-name/`

Comment: Do I have to add any rewrite rules using `add_rewrite_rules()` or the `rewrite_rules_array` filter? I've tried that before and it might have been the cause of an unusual redirection on the site

Comment: no extra rewrites necessary, that's what the rewrite slug of `register_post_type` takes care of. do you have a front prefix on your post permalinks? you may need to add `'with_front' => false` if that's the case. the above code is tested and working in twentytwelve theme.

Comment: The Permalinks option in Settings > Permalinks is set to 'Post Name' and all `with_front` options are set to false. After flushing the rules, neither `example.com/business/` nor `example.com/business/long-island-city/business-name` work :/

Comment: `example.com/business/business-name/` won't work, there's no rewrite rule to handle that. if you mean `example.com/business/` should show a post type archive, then you have to set `'has_archive' => 'business'`. I have no explanation as to why your post type links aren't working though, without seeing your present code. I assume you're correctly registering types on `init` and have set the arguments as I have them above.

Comment: How does WordPress interpret the `%location%` in the `rewrite` option of `register_post_type`? Is it solely for our interpretation in the rewriting of the links in `post_type_links`? Or is there something else going on as well?

Comment: `%location%` is the rewrite tag created when the location taxonomy is registered, and allows WordPress to properly generate the rewrite rule to resolve requests for business posts. the pattern is: `business/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$`, so `/business/foo/bar/` will match that pattern, and query for a business post where `bar` is the post's name. it will also set the location query var for the corresponding location, so you could easily grab that value in your template. you could generate rules manually and make it work, it's just simpler this way letting WordPress do the work for you.

Comment: you may also want to check out [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/), which will show you the generated rewrite rules, and how WordPress is interpreting requests.

Comment: Accessing a URL without the `location` tax slug redirects me to `/business/%location%/business-name` (%location% as literal) with a bad request error... hmm I've got to figure this out. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: that happens because the `%` character has meaning in a URL, it's used for [URL-encoded characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). I'll guess you're using firefox to test this, webkit browsers will automatically convert `%` to the url-encoded `%25`, and the request will resolve correctly. if you want URLs to work without setting a location, you'll have to swap that for some default placeholder if a location hasn't been assigned. the term doesn't actually have to exist, since it's not used in the query that loads the post.

Comment: Ah that's right. The weird thing is I just tried the same method again with replacing the `business` slug to `business/%location%/`, and now the `business/long-island-city/` and `/business/long-island-city/business-name/` URLs are working, but `/business/` was showing me a 404, even though there's an archive page set. Something weird is up with this theme, I'm going to keep digging through.