# Post Type Rewrite Custom

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Demo for example:

- `my-site.com/shop-virtual/` - Listing all posts of Post type "Products".
- `my-site.com/shop-virtual/products/category` - Listing all posts of Category.
- `my-site.com/shop-virtual/products/category/my-product-single` - Single post

`/shop-virtual/` this is custom page with loop for post_type 'products'.

Currently looks like this:

- `my-site.com/shop-virtual/` - page list
- `my-site.com/category/my-category` - For categories is thus with base categories of wp.
- `my-site.com/products/my-product` - this is single page of unique product.

I tried to use the 'rewrite' the 'register_post_type' that way down but it did not work

```
register_post_type( 'products', array(
    ...
    'rewrite' => array("slug" => "shop-virtual/products", "with_front" => false),
) );
```

Comment: see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105789/4771).

Comment: But this works for normal category of wordpress?