# Custom Permalink Tag breaks Pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Most the below work stems from a [previous question / accepted answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types). I'm trying to achieve the following permalink structure:

```
/listings/
/listings/page/2/
/listings/%state%/
/listings/%state%/page/2/
/listings/%state%/property/post-title/
```

I thought it was going to be a simple task but I keep running into more and more issues. Currently, all the above works **except pagination**.

My **Post Type** ( `cpt_listings` ) rewrite looks like this:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'listings/%tax_states%/property', 'with_front' => false )
```

My **Taxonomy** ( `tax_states` ) rewrite looks like this:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'listings', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true )
```

I use this function to replace `%state%` with the actual taxonomy term:

```
/** Process the State Taxonomy Permalink Tag **/
function state_permalink( $permalink, $post_id, $leavename ) {

    if( false === strpos( $permalink, '%tax_states%' ) ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    // Get post
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if( empty( $post ) ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    // Get taxonomy terms
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'tax_states' );   
    if( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) && ! empty( $terms ) && is_object( $terms[0] ) ) {
        $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    } else {
        $taxonomy_slug = 'united-states';
    }

    return str_replace( '%tax_states%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink );
}
add_filter('post_link',      'state_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'state_permalink', 10, 3);
```

Finally, I have these custom rewrites in place:

```
/** Rewrites to allow our permalinks to work **/
/** This fixes `/listings/%tax_states%/` **/
/** This fixes `listings/%tax_states%/property/post-title/` **/
function type_tax_rewrites( $rules ) {
    $new = array();
    $new['listings/([^/]+)/property/(.+)/?$']   = 'index.php?cpt_listings=$matches[2]';
    $new['listings/(.+)/?$']                    = 'index.php?tax_states=$matches[1]';

    return array_merge( $new, $rules ); // Ensure our rules come first
}
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'type_tax_rewrites' );
```

Since all the above works besides pagination I feel like I'm doing something wrong here. I almost feel like WordPress should be handling the rewrites and I wouldn't need to rewrite every scenario.

I've printed out my `$wp_query` in a `template_redirect` hook to see what the Query Variables are and these stuck out:

```
[tax_states] => 2,
[paged]      => 0,
```

So, `tax_states` is taking the paged variable and I've been playing around with rewriting it but I am unfamiliar with how the rewrite system works and as I've stated above it just seems like I'm doing something wrong if I even have to rewrite for pagination. Here's the rewrite combinations I've appended to the above `rewrite_rules_array` hook:

```
$new['listings/page/([0-9]+)/?$']  = 'index.php?paged=$matches[1]';
$new['listings/page/([0-9]+)/?$']  = 'index.php?tax_states=$matches[1]';
```

Neither of the above seem to do anything different, pagination still leads to 404s.

**The Core of My Question Is**

1. Am I doing the permalink tag correctly? Is there a better / easier way to do it?
2. How can I fix pagination and keep the permalink structure described above?

Comment: `/listings/%state%/2/` would be `/listings/%state%/page/2/`. your issue is probably the extra rules added for your taxonomy because you've defined it as hierarchical.

Comment: @Milo would it be easier to *not* make it hierarchical? Really, I'm assigning the term programmatically so it wouldn't matter either way. Also, it's not just broken on the taxonomy page but on the actual post type archive page too. The permalink structure above was a typo.

Comment: yes, it would be easier to set is an non-hierarchical, it'll remove all the rules to support multiple levels of tax terms. [here is an answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105789/4771) I wrote for a similar question. note that the order you register your tax and post type in matters.

Comment: @Milo - Thanks for the help! Changed it from hierarchical to non and it worked instantly ( even with `query_var` set ). All issues fixed, structure how I wanted it. Now, do I mark this question as duplicate, delete it, or would you like to add an expanded answer and I'll accept it :D ?

Comment: I'm out the door right now, you can add your working code as an answer or mark it duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Milo's help the code in the question ended up working: permalinks fixed and the structure stayed exactly how I wanted it described in the question above.

1. Removed the `rewrite_rules_array` hook entirely
2. Moved my taxonomy registration above my post type registration
3. Changed the taxonomy to be non-hierarchical `'hierarchical' => false`

From my limited understand of how it works based on what Milo was describing is that the built-in WordPress rewrites that handle Hierarchical Taxonomies interferes with the structure I was trying to achieve, I can only assume because of `/parent-term/child-term/` rewrites. The built-in `tag` already achieves the structure I was going for which is why non-hierarchical end up working.